# r128 driver not loaded

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, lubuntu

I have now successfully installed Lubuntu, only to find that something is very wrong with the graphics. `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` gave me this output:

```
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r128_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r128_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/r128_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/r128_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/r128_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/r128_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r128_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: r128
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

The graphics card is an ATI Rage 128, so it found that right driver, but isn't loading it. Does anyone know where it is, or what is wrong? xserver-xorg-video-r128 is installed.

There is a file  `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so`. Should I ln -s is to the file it's looking for?

Answer (score 1):

1. Better to copy it:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r128_dri.so
   ```
2. Check also if its kernel module is loaded:

   ```
   lsmod | grep r128
   ```

   - If it's not loaded, Add `r128` to `/etc/modules` and the running in place (`blacklist ...`) to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
   - Then run:

     ```
     sudo update-initramfs -u
     ```